# How to change the way to switch between apps

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

When I double-click on the home button it shows all the opened apps. In the latest version of IOS, the apps are overlaid onto one another. Swiping left or right is so fast that it makes it hard to really stop on the right app to close it. Maybe it's just me :)

I just loved the way it was before where instead of being overlaid, the app where side by side and it was much easier. Anybody know if there is a way to change this overlay display for side by side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - but why do you feel the need to 'close' apps - i.e. Force Quit them.

The only time you ever need to do that is if they stop responding correctly, the rest off the time they will be perfectly happy to sit in the background, until memory gets short, then they are quietly dropped from active memory, leaving only a small footprint until they are needed again.

If it's to prevent them from being active whilst in the background, then it would be better to switch off Background App Refresh, in Settings > General.

Comment: Ohhh, I didn't know about that. Thanks now I don't need to do that anymore :)